# Filtering Django JSONB items in list

Tags: django, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Django `data` JSONField with the following data in

```
{
    "title": "Some Title",
    "projects": [
        {"name": "Project 1", "score": "5"},
        {"name": "Project 2", "score": "10"},
        {"name": "Project 3", "score": "2"},
    ]
}
```

And I need to filter rows by project scores (numeric type), i.e. `where project -> score <= 5`

Django ORM provides the basics of filtering and working with a Postgres JSONB field. That is, I can do

```
Model.objects.filter(data__title="Some Title")
```

But it is not so straight forward when having a list of items in the JSON column, i.e. I can't do

```
Model.objects.filter(data__projects__score__lte=5)

Only way I can reach the `score` in Django ORM is to use the array index, i.e.

Model.objects.filter(data__projects__0__score__lte=5)
```

But that doesn't really work now, I'm interested in all items in that list, which can be however many

**Where I am currently:**

I've joined that list to the queryset as a `jsonb_array_elements`

```
queryset.query.join(join=join_cfg)
```

Which appended the following sql to the QUERY

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements("my_table"."data" -> 'projects') projects ON TRUE
```

Now, in Raw SQL, I can do something like this to filter that list

```
WHERE (projects->>'score')::numeric < 5
```

Problem is I can't get this to play nicely with the Django ORM

Currently, I'm adding this `WHERE` clause using `queryset.extra()`

```
queryset = queryset.extra(where=where_clause)
```

Problem with this is that by using `.extra()`, the WHERE clause is `AND`ed at the end of the query, which produces unexpected results in combination with other filters that are done using Django `Q` objects.

I.e.  The final WHERE clause generated looks like this:

```
WHERE condition1 AND (condition2 OR condition3) AND MY_CUSTOM_WHERE_CONDITION

// but what I need is 

WHERE condition1 AND (condition2 OR condition3 OR MY_CUSTOM_WHERE_CONDITION)
```

Ideally, this custom condition should be added with a `Q` object, i.e.

```
query_filters |= Q(projects__score__lte=5)
```

But with the `projects` column being a custom join, I get  `Cannot resolve keyword 'projects' into field.` So I can't use the django ORM on it to filter the same way I filter `title` in the beginning of this post

---

I think this custom join has to be annotated somehow and then use the `Q` object on that annotated column, but I can't get this to work.

I've tried, extra select, annotations with RawSQL, FilteredRelation, everything..

Any help is appreciated. Thank you